# Is it possible to obtain index value from Singly linked list?

Tags: python, list, indexing, singly-linked-list

Suppose I have a singly linked list generated as:

```
# Singly Linked List
class node:
  def __init__(self,data=None):
    self.data=data
    self.next=None

class linked_list:
  def __init__(self):
    self.head=node()

# Adds new node containing 'data' to the end of the linked list.
  def append(self,data):
    new_node=node(data)
    cur=self.head
    while cur.next!=None:
        cur=cur.next
    cur.next=new_node

# Returns the length (integer) of the linked list.
  def length(self):
    cur=self.head
    total=0
    while cur.next!=None:
        total+=1
        cur=cur.next
    return total

# Prints out the linked list in traditional Python list format.
  def display(self):
    elems=[]
    cur_node=self.head
    while cur_node.next!=None:
        cur_node=cur_node.next
        elems.append(cur_node.data)
    print elems

# Returns the value of the node at 'index'.
  def get(self,index):
    if index>=self.length():
        print "ERROR: 'Get' Index out of range!"
        return None
    cur_idx=0
    cur_node=self.head
    while True:
        cur_node=cur_node.next
        if cur_idx==index: return cur_node.data
        cur_idx+=1

# Deletes the node at index 'index'.
  def erase(self,index):
    if index>=self.length():
        print "ERROR: 'Erase' Index out of range!"
        return
    cur_idx=0
    cur_node=self.head
    while True:
        last_node=cur_node
        cur_node=cur_node.next
        if cur_idx==index:
            last_node.next=cur_node.next
            return
        cur_idx+=1

#Allows for bracket operator syntax (i.e. a[0] to return first item).
  def __getitem__(self,index):
    return self.get(index)


  def getindex(self,data):
    cur_node = self.data
    while True:
      cur_node = cur_node.next
        if cur_node == data:
            return cur_node.index
            break
        index +=1
```

And suppose I create a singly linked list as:

```
new_list = linked_list()
new_list.append(5)
new_list.append(6)
new_list.append(8)
```

Suppose I want to delete the 2nd value in the list (index 1) which happens to be the value 6 but I don't know what's the index for 6. How would I be able to find the index value of 6 and use it to delete 6? Or is there another way to delete a value from a singly linked list without knowing the index value?

EDIT: I've added a new module called getindex that should theoretically grab the index when a node is specified but I've gotten this error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'. Its referring to the cur_node=cur_node.next line in the getindex module. How do I fix this error?

Comment: You could add an attribute to the node that denotes index when .append() is called.

Comment: @Q.Holness How could I add an attribute to the node to denote the index?

Comment: In your `get` function you have it almost ready, instead of returning `data` return `index`, and instead of comparing `index` compare `data`.

Comment: According to Linked List theory, the preferred method is to iterate through all elements and delete the desired element when you reach it.

Comment: @scope I've added another function but it doesn't seem to be working. Any inputs?

Comment: @superasiantomtom95 You made some really basic mistakes there, look at my answer.

Comment: If you need to use index, linked list is a bad structure for you.

Answer (score -1):

This is the function which you need:

```
  def getIndex(self,data):
    cur_idx=0
    cur_node=self.head
    while cur_node.next:
        cur_node=cur_node.next
        if cur_node.data==data: return cur_idx
        cur_idx+=1
    return None
```

And you use it like this:

```
new_list = linked_list()
new_list.append(5)
new_list.append(6)
new_list.append(8)
new_list.display()
idx = new_list.getIndex(6)
if idx != None:
    new_list.erase(idx)
new_list.display()
```